# using System.Windows.Forms in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to use System.Windows.Forms classes in Xamarin.Forms?!
I have a windows application and I want to use its classes in my Xamarin.Forms app, including the classes that have used windows.forms.
For example I have a class that's used TreeNode, I can't find a suitable equivalent class in xamarin so I was wondering if there's a possibility of using windows.forms in xamarin projects because right now it doesn't recognize windows.forms namespace, it just lets me use windows.forms.Input

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not going to work and most likely (and hopefully) will never be possible. I also think that is not something that you should want.

Both WinForms and Xamarin.Forms do kind of the same thing: provide a UI for your application. But the UI you want to have for your mobile app should be a lot different than one on the desktop. We've tried putting desktop applications on mobile with Windows CE, let's never ever do that again.

The mobile paradigm has a lot of very specific UI elements and concepts that only work on a mobile device. Porting a current application should make you rethink that.

For your question: I can't make up what you're trying to do exactly, but it seems that you are trying to port an existing app to mobile with Xamarin, great! Try to reuse as much code as possible, but from the business logic. Not your UI. Specifically you are asking for a TreeNode, I think there is a reason that these aren't available on mobile, you probably want to show a list on the highest level and whenever someone selects an option, you navigate to the next page and drill down into your data.

Although this is not a answer to your question, I hope it helps you understand that you might want to rethink your approach on things.

For some more advanced Xamarin.Forms controls you can either turn to GitHub and search through there, build your own, or have a look at third-party vendors like Telerik, DevExpress or Syncfusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation

Comment: No problem, please accept it as an answer if it helped you!