# Is it possible to add a System.windows.form reference to a Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am developing a **Xamarin.Forms** app in Visual Studio and I need to use an **external SDK** that is **dedicated for Windows Form apps**. I have been trying to add a reference to System.Windoes.Form but it doesn't appear in the assemblies. 
I know it wouldn't make sense using windows forms in a Xamarin project, but I am creating the user interface with Xamarin graphics, I just need to add the reference to Windows.Forms to get rid of the following error:

*Can not resolve reference: `System.Windows.Forms`, referenced by `MY DLL`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Windows.Forms`, or remove the reference to `MYDLL`.*

Is there a way to do so? 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using System.Windows.Forms in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769118/using-system-windows-forms-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: In that question he is asking if he can use actively the forms in a Xamarin app. I am asking only about the reference... I will not use windows forms. But thanks for suggesting the link @AccessDenied

Comment: it's pretty much the same, if you use winforms 3-rd party component you will use winforms.

Comment: @AccessDenied I have been using that SDK in a previous project and the component does not interact with the user interface. It is used only in the business logic...

Comment: then find netstandard port or find another crossplatform SDK.

Comment: It would be useful to specify which SDK you are talking about

Comment: @NoWayHandshake did you find an answer for this?  Is there a way to stub or mock out the reference?

Answer (score 1):

.NET can be categorized into three and those are, .NET Core, .NET Framework and Xamarin.

The .NET Framework supports Windows and Web applications.

.NET Core is the new open-source and cross-platform framework to build applications for all operating system including Windows, Mac, and Linux.

When you want to build mobile (iOS, Android, and Windows Mobile) apps using C#, Xamarin is your only choice.

You cannot use `System.Windows.Forms` inside a Xamarin Project and it is incompatible.