# Can't find System.Windows.Forms Assembly reference

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2019

So I'm using visual studio 2019, making an android app with C# code.

In the image you will see below I tried to find the System.Windows.Forms assembly reference after going through the typical

right-click-->Add reference-->Assemblies tab

Process only to find the reference isn't there at all. Does anyone know why I can't find it?

[Reference pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1U6K.png)

Comment: This question has been asked and answered. Try searching a bit before posting your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261158/is-it-possible-to-add-a-system-windows-form-reference-to-a-xamarin-project

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't able to find that in all my searching.